# Finding ties in top values per row?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here's my sample data:

```
declare @cities table 
(
    city varchar(100),
    toyota int,
    honda int,
    hyundai int,
    ford int,
    chevy int
)

insert into @cities
select 'miami', 23, 65, 30, 65,12 union
select 'san francisco', 12, 7,3, 7,12 union
select 'houston', 6,3, null, 5, 4
```

I can find the max value per row with simple `where` statements, something like this:

```
select count(*) from @cities where toyota > honda and toyora > hyundai...
```

But let's say I want to the max value, but also see if there's anyone else that has that max value. In other, I'm trying to find who tied for 1st place.

So the ideal result would be *miami* and *san francisco* because both cities are tied for top value (ie. *honda* and *ford* tied in 1st place in *miami* and *toyota* and *chevy* tied for *1st place* in *san francisco*).

Comment: can you change your model?  normalizing the table will solve your problem. Thing get complicated if you want add more columns Like Chrisler, BMW, Mercedez, Ferrari ... Because first you need found out the max of each row and then which one have more that one match.

Comment: You can solve it unsing [**UNPIVOT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)

Comment: I can normalize the data, but it's saved the way I posted.

Comment: You're right. I never considered using `unpivot`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT` and `DENSE_RANK`.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/LIQ50654)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT city, brand, qty
    FROM (SELECT  city, toyota, honda, hyundai, ford, chevy 
          FROM  @cities) p
    UNPIVOT ( qty FOR brand IN (toyota, honda, hyundai, ford, chevy)
            ) as unpvt
), top_brands as (
    SELECT *, dense_rank() over (partition by city order by qty desc ) as rnk
    FROM cte
)

SELECT city
FROM top_brands
GROUP BY city
HAVING COUNT(case when rnk = 1 then 1 end) > 1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]